# Eliminar caracteres consecutivos de una lista en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Muy buenas a todos, a ver si me podéis ayudar.
Tengo un problema cuando quiero eliminar de una lista todos los elementos consecutivos que cumpla con la condición de que sea una mayúscula y otra minúscula y que me devuelva el resto de la lista.
Ejemplo: Dada una secuencia:
 **"aAbBaa"** el resultado sea **"aa"** o este otro ejemplo **"cCBb"** el resultado sea **""**
Tengo esta implementación:

```
removerInversos :: secuencia -> secuencia
removerInversos []  = []
removerInversos (x:xs)
    | isInverse x cabezaCola == True = cola
    | otherwise =  x: removerInversos  cola 
    where
    cabezaCola = head xs
    cola = tail xs
```

La función `isInverse`:

```
isInverse :: Operador -> Operador -> Bool
isInverse x y = (match x y) && ( ((isUpper x) && (isLower y))|| ((isLower x) && (isUpper y)) )
```

Función `match`:

```
match :: Operador -> Operador -> Bool
match x y = (toUpper x) == (toUpper y)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?¿Para qué usas `ultimo`?¿Para qué comparar `isInverse x cabezaCola` con `True`? Se me ocurren mejoras, pero no sé qué es lo que buscas. Te sugiero añadir el código de `isInverse` para que esta pregunta sea de más utilidad a los interesados por ella.

Comment: Lo que quiero comparar son dos elementos consecutivos en una lista que tengan la condición de que una sea mayúscula y otra minúscula "Aa", y que me devuelva el resto de la lista, y si en el resto de la lista se ha vuelto a juntar otra minúscula y otra mayúscula, haga otra pasada y lo elimine. Ejemplos:
"aAaa" me devuelva "aa"
"aABb" me devuelva " "
"aaaaAbbB" me devuelva "aaab"
En mi código solo hace una pasada, y aparte de eso, tiene algunos fallos, como por ejemplo para la secuencia "aa" me devuelve solo "a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Porqué falla

Para ver lo que te pasa, veamos qué hace tu código para `removerInversos "ab"`:

1. `removerInversos "ab"`
2. Como `isInverse x cabezaCola == False` --> `'a' : removerInversos cola`

En este paso, `cabezaCola == 'b'` y `cola == ""`. Estás perdiendo la `cabezaCola`, es ahí donde pierdes elementos.

### Primer versión: recursiva

Hagamoslo de otra forma:

```
removerInversos :: Secuencia -> Secuencia
removerInversos []  = []
removerInversos [x] = [x]
removerInversos (x:y:xs) | isInverse x y = removerInversos xs
                         | otherwise     = x: removerInversos (y:xs) 

isInverse :: Operador -> Operador -> Bool
isInverse x y = (toUpper x == toUpper y) && (isUpper x /= isUpper y)
```

Con esta comprobación de patrones se evita tener que usar `head` y `tail`.

Pero dices de volver a repetir por si se vuelve a cumplir la condición, que se podría hacer así:

```
removerInversos' :: Secuencia -> Secuencia
removerInversos' xs | sinMasCambios = xs
                    | otherwise     = removerInversos' ys
  where
    ys = removerInversos xs
    sinMasCambios = length xs == length ys
```

Aunque no resulta nada elegante.

### Segunda versión: foldr

Habría otra forma de enfocar el problema. Si hacemos un pliegue por la derecha, `foldr`, tenemos la seguridad de que la cola ya ha sido procesada antes de hacer la comprobación, algo que nos evita aplicar la recursividad:

```
removerInversos :: Secuencia -> Secuencia
removerInversos = foldr aux []
  where 
    aux :: Operador -> Secuencia -> Secuencia
    aux x [] = [x]
    aux x (y:ys) | isInverse x y = ys
                 | otherwise     = x:y:ys
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Chema, sabía que perdía ese carácter pero no encontraba la manera de solucionarlo. Me vale perfectamente las 3 maneras, se ajustan a lo que necesito. Si me surge cualquier otra duda, te lo haré saber.
Un saludo, y gracias de nuevo